# Android service not showing in `service list`

Tags: android, android-source

I have a background system service running on my android (priv-app), and I can create and start it properly with:

```
# am start-service  -n <my service>
```

It starts properly and I can see it running wiht `ps -A`, but `service list` does not show it.

I would like to call its methods using `am start -a <myservice>.doSomething`. I never see a "client" binding to it.

I can see the service running in dumpsys tho:

```
  * ServiceRecord{ea1df4c u0 com.foo.bar.platformprovision/.PlatformProvisionService}
    intent={cmp=com.foo.bar.platformprovision/.PlatformProvisionService}
    packageName=com.foo.bar.platformprovision
    processName=com.foo.bar.platformprovision
    permission=android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE
    baseDir=/system/priv-app/bar_platformprovision_debug/platformprovision_debug.apk
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.foo.bar.platformprovision
    app=ProcessRecord{3f8a209 19448:com.foo.bar.platformprovision/u0a113}
    createTime=-21m13s353ms startingBgTimeout=--
    lastActivity=-21m2s910ms restartTime=-21m2s910ms createdFromFg=true
    startRequested=true delayedStop=false stopIfKilled=false callStart=true lastStartId=1
```

My `onBind` code looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "XXX: Service bond");

    IBinder ib = (IBinder) new RemotePlatformServiceImp();
    return ib;
  }
```

Two questions:

1. why I do not see my process running in `service list`
2. How to call methods (from AIDL) from adb properly?

Answer (score 2):

This command  `adb shell service list` only shows system services. App services won't show there.

If your service is in an app, even if that app is a system app, it doesn't make it a "system service". These services are the ones started by [SystemServer](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java;l=178?q=SystemServer), like for example [AudioService](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/audio/AudioService.java;l=175?q=AudioService&sq=)

`adb shell dumpsys activity services` will show info for apps services.

As for the second question, as far as I know `adb shell service call XXXX` also would work only for system services.